# Xamarin.Forms - Click image from custom rendered camera & display in Xamarin.form(xaml)

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin.forms development. I got stuck in following scenario.
I have MainPage.xaml file which contains custom rendered camera view & a button to click picture,In .Droid solution I have 'CustomRenderer.cs' & 'CameraPreview.cs' files to render native camera view of android into MainPage.xaml,and 'CameraClickImplementation.cs' which is implementing the 'PhotoClick.cs' interface to click photo & save on external storage. Currently I am successfully able to click picture & save it on external storage of my android device. 
Now my requirement is to get some callback after saving image on external storage to MainPage.xaml.cs. i.e. from 'CameraClickImplementation.cs' to MainPage.xaml.cs to display it on MainPage.xaml.

Following is code for some part of my MainPage.xaml.

```xml
<StackLayout x:Name="CamArea" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,1,1">
    <local:CameraPreview Camera="Rear" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

Following is code for some part of my MainPage.xaml.cs file.

```cs
void GalleryClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var gallery = DependencyService.Get<IPhotoClick>();
    if (gallery != null)
    {
         gallery.TakePic();
    }
}
```

Following is code for some part of my CameraClickImplementation.cs file.

```cs
public void OnPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
{
    Android.Content.Context context = MainActivity.Instance;
    Android.Net.Uri uriTarget = context.ContentResolver.Insert(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, new Android.Content.ContentValues());
 //  String SHARED_FILE_NAME = "shared.png";
    SavePictureToDisk("sample",data);

    //camera.StartPreview();
}

public void SavePictureToDisk(string filename, byte[] imageData)
{
    Android.Content.Context context = MainActivity.Instance;
   // var dir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath);
   var dir= Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;

   string name = filename + ".jpg";
   // string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(pictures, name);
    string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, name);
    try
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, imageData);
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
    Toast.MakeText(context, "Image saved", ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

Can anybody please help me in this??

Comment: Hi, would you mind post your project on github, so I can do it based on your project.